# Docker is pulling image from remote registry but I want to use a local image

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I have this simple run command:

```
docker run -d --name interos-jenkins interos-jenkins
```

but I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: manifest for
> example.com/interos-jenkins:latest not found

So for whatever reason docker is looking the image in the remote register, if I run `docker images` locally, I see:

```
REPOSITORY                                                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
example.com/interos-jenkins                                    latest              28b0ffed29d5        21 minutes ago      766MB
interos-jenkins                                                latest              28b0ffed29d5        21 minutes ago      766MB
example.com/interos_jenkins                                    latest              57fe1cbff2dc        About an hour ago   742MB
interos_jenkins                                                latest              57fe1cbff2dc        About an hour ago   742MB
example.com/interos                                            latest              349f61f0ba59        2 days ago          486MB
interos                                                        latest              349f61f0ba59        2 days ago          486MB
example.com/interos                                            latest              94b44ccbc9d1        2 days ago          486MB
ubuntu                                                         16.04               a3551444fc85        2 days ago          119MB
python                                                         3.7-alpine          715a1f28828d        4 days ago          87MB
jenkins/jenkins                                                lts                 15625611d6fb        2 weeks ago         704MB
centos                                                         latest              9f38484d220f        6 weeks ago         202MB
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch                  6.3.2               96dd1575de0f        9 months ago        826MB
jenkins                                                        latest              cd14cecfdb3a        9 months ago        696MB
```

so does anyone know why this is happening and how I can use the local images instead of the remote?

*My guess is that the first match for "interos-jenkins" has the remote url in it?*

Update, nvm, I was running this command beforehand and didn't realize it:

```
docker pull "$endpoint"/interos-jenkins:latest
```

I guess I still want to know if there is a way to tell docker to run an image from a remote url or to run the local one.

Answer (score 1):

Normally docker checks first locally if the image is present and then tries to connect to a remote repository.

What happens in your case is correct because the image you try to run indeed is not present locally. The name of the image is the full name: repository/name:tag

Can you please try the docker run command specifying the full name for the image?

If you want to run the command in the short form you will need to retag the image with the short name only (no repository name).

Hope this helps